# Convert <input type="time"> value (as duration) to float of hours JS/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a database table where one of the fields - "Duration" - is a FLOAT type instead of TIME, i.e. 3.5 hours instead of "03:30:00". This is done for DB performance reasons and ease of programming.
For UI reasons I am updating my front-end form field to

```
<input id="duration" type="time">
```

which produces values of TIME format. Is there a shorthand way of converting TIME to FLOAT?

So far I'm thinking something like

```
function timeToFloat(){

    var buff = $('#duration').val().split(':'); //to array
    buff.pop(); //remove seconds
    return parseInt(buff[0]) + parseFloat( buff[1] / 60 ).toFixed(2);

}
```

in JS, or PHP:

```
function timeToFloat( $duration ){

     $duration = explode(":", $duration);
     array_pop($duration);
     return $duration[0] + numberFormat( $duration[1] / 60, 2 );

}
```

Anyone knows better?

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#attr-input-type  You could try type="number"  Unless I'm misunderstanding your question

Comment: If you are just asking how to convert the time to float before inserting to the database, I would ask why you are trying to do that on the frontend rather than the backend.

Comment: I need to make it type="time" for UI reasons as per clients request, but I want to keep the values in float for ease of use and performance. Front-end/back-end doesn't really matter.

Comment: The html5 time and number have different allowed values.  If you mean you want it to be set as a float, but be a time, I'm not sure that is possible.  In regard to the frontend vs backend, it does matter a bit from a security standpoint, because the backend is fully in your control, and it's one thing to rely on the frontend to give you the correct data, and it's another to have the backend validate the input and convert it to the format it needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it in MySql

`SELECT TIME_TO_SEC('03:30:00')/3600;
 3.5000`

Comment: I think this might do. Can I do this during row insertion? Like, `"INSERT INTO table (a, b, c) VALUES (1, 2, TIME_TO_SEC('03:30:00')/3600)"?`

Comment: Yes you can, and you can convert back using `SEC_TO_TIME` example here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c0805/3